# Legacy autograd function with non-static forward method is deprecated

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, deep-learning

During the Training of the CFNet (https://github.com/gallenszl/CFNet),
after loading Mish activation, the error comes:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qz87F.png)

RuntimeError: Legacy autograd function with non-static forward method is deprecated. Please use new-style autograd function with static forward method. (Example: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#torch.autograd.Function)

anybody knows how to fix it?

Comment: Please post the error as text, not an image.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're using a pytorch version that is too new where some incompatible changes have been introduced. Use the pytorch (and python) versions indicated by their repository. In this case for pytorch this is version `1.1.0`.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. yes I am using new version of pytorch but I am not sure that if this non-static autograd method still works on older version or not

Comment: and I think that pytorch 1.1.0 is not available more

Comment: You can try it by installing the older version: And they all are definitely still available via conda (or even via pip): https://anaconda.org/pytorch/pytorch/files?version=1.1.0  https://pypi.org/project/torch/1.1.0/ I recommend installing it and just trying it. It is usually a large amount of work to convert code to a never version with breaking changes.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to install it in windows? and if yes, how?

Comment: It is, check out the instructions: https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/windows.html